# GROUP BY doesn't show all fields

Tags: mysql, group-by

**NEW UPDATE**: I first sort by a different field called 'fav'

The `$result` of the `$query` only shows the field `$row['symbol']`, it doesn't show  the field `$row['id']`. What am I doing wrong?

```
    CREATE TABLE `tableName` (
  `id` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `symbol` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fav` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL
```

)

```
$query = "SELECT symbol FROM (SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY fav DESC ) AS t GROUP BY t.symbol ";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo 'id: '.$row['id'].' symbol: '.$row['symbol'].'<BR>';
    }
}
```

I'm using PHP 7.4.16

**UPDATE**: With PHP 8.0.3 I get this ERROR MESSAGE:

> Warning: Undefined array key "id"

It's like it doesn't find the the id, however if I run it like this it works fine:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY symbol DESC";
```

Comment: You only `SELECT symbol`, you don't `SELECT id, symbol` or `SELECT *`.

Comment: If I put *, it doesn't work with 7.4.16, if I put id, symbol it doesn't work either. And I do select * in the second part of the query, so it should show $row['id'], but it doesn't

Comment: You can only select the columns you grouped by. Doesn't have any logic you select id unique for grouped rows. And your problem is exclusively SQL

Comment: ```SELECT `t`.*``` or ```SELECT `t`.`symbol`, `t`.`column_name1`, `t`.`column_name2```

Comment: @vee, I thought your suggestion was going to work, but I tried all 3: `t`.* | 't'.* | t.* ( with a comma logically ) and it didn't work.

Comment: @Leandro Bardelli, I group by symbol, not by id ;o)

Comment: @sebseb but you want show a field

Comment: I don't have your table structure so this is what I tried on my PC and it's working. https://postimg.cc/xJ83FCf5

Comment: Suppose you have three rows with the same symbol, with IDs 1, 2, and 3, which of those 3 IDs are you expecting to be returned, and why?

Comment: Since you do not use any aggregate function, why use GROUP BY at all. Just use ORDER BY.

Comment: @vee working is not same that useful or clear

Comment: @GarethD, good question. I actually would like to just show the symbol, and then the 3 id's for just one symbol. So, all 3.

Comment: @vee, I tried your postimg.cc/xJ83FCf5 but it doesn't work at my end. And I tried it in both SELECT's of each " sub query ".

Comment: If you want to show all ids then please update the question details because  your current question just `id` column doesn't show while `t.*` should show all columns.

Comment: Maybe post a good sample of tableName rows, and then also what the query should return.

Comment: @lukas.j , I actually use an ORDER BY first. Also,  GROUP BY never worked in my server. So, for once I wanted to make it working. But I always have this same issue.

Comment: So if you need all the IDs, then you don't need group by at all, what you need to do is `ORDER BY Symbol`, then in your application layer deal with it e.g. check symbol with each iteration, and when it changes start a new line, or however you want to output the data. Alternatively, use `GROUP_CONCAT` along with `GROUP BY` to concatenate all the IDs into a single column. It really depends what you need, as to what the best solution is.

Comment: @GarethD, I actually have more fields, and I ORDER BY a different field. I just wanted to simplify it.

Comment: @sebseb: that is the issue – you have more fields. This is very important to know when it comes to GROUP BY.

Comment: @lukas.j thanks, I just made a new update

Comment: @sebseb: once again, why are you using GROUP BY when you do not use an aggregate function (or GROUP_CONCAT, see my answer below). Just use ORDER BY. Also the outer query is unnecessary (with the information you gave us till now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the question. My best guess is that GROUP BY is not needed:

```
  SELECT symbol,
         fav,
         id
    FROM tableName
ORDER BY symbol DESC,
         fav DESC,
         id
```

Another possibility would be to gather all the ids per symbol:

```
  SELECT symbol,
         GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ', ')
    FROM tableName
GROUP BY symbol DESC
```

Edit to include column *fav*:

```
  SELECT symbol,
         fav,
         GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ', ') AS ids
    FROM tableName
GROUP BY symbol DESC,
         fav DESC
ORDER BY symbol DESC,
         fav DESC
```

Comment: The second one works, but when I add the " ORDER BY fav DESC " it doesn't work.

Comment: That is because it is not part of the query. I'll edit it.

Comment: Thanks, this later one with the 'fav' column works, but still is not showing the $row['id']. So, I assume it's a problem with my MAMP server, which I already reinstalled.

Comment: The third columns should show the _ids_ concatenated with commas for each _symbol_ & _fav_ combination. If you want each _id_ on its on row in the resultset, then use my first example (which does not use GROUP BY).

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to discern your intent from your SQL query. Your query is this.

```sql
SELECT symbol 
  FROM (
      SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY symbol DESC 
       ) AS t
 GROUP BY t.symbol
```

It means the same thing as this. (I omitted the ORDER BY because ORDER BY operations in subqueries aren't guaranteed to carry through to outer queries.)

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT symbol FROM tableName
```

Neither of these queries returns an `id` column. That's why your php reference to `$row['id']` fails.

Is it possible you want `ORDER BY` rather than `GROUP BY`? In that case your query would be

```sql
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY symbol DESC
```

Or, is it possible you have duplicate `symbol` values in your table, and you want the `id` of just one of the duplicate rows? In that case you want something like this.

```sql
SELECT MAX(id) id, symbol
  FROM tableName
 GROUP BY symbol
 ORDER BY symbol DESC
```

The query finds the largest id value for each distinct value of symbol and returns it.

Comment: the SELECT DISTINCT works perfectly. But then when I add the ORDER BY it doesn't work. ORDER BY fav DESC [ see NEW UPDATE please ].

Comment: @sebseb: You should now really post a reasonable set of example rows. Without that we are all just guessing (as you might have noticed by now).